# How to remove label from axis of plot using plotly?

Tags: pandas, numpy, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I want to remove the `P1` label from the x-axis, while still keeping the `Patient` label for all my plots.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px

all_patients_df = (treatment_df.set_axis(treatment_df.index.str.replace(r'_P\d', '', regex=True).set_names('group')).groupby(['patient', 'time', 'group']).mean().reset_index(['patient', 'time'], drop=False))

for gene in all_patients_df.columns:
  obs = all_patients_df[[gene, "time", "patient"]] # observations
  obs.columns = ["gene expression", "time", "patient"]

  fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=obs["patient"], y=obs[obs["time"]==hr]["gene expression"], name=hr) for hr in obs["time"].unique()])
  fig.update_layout(title=gene, xaxis_title="Patient", yaxis_title="Gene expression")
  fig.show()
```

[image]

Data:

`all_patients_df.head().to_dict()`

```
{'DNAJA1': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.378391959798995,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.3302658486707567,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.16458333333333336,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.19790575916230363,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.21559633027522937},
 'DNAJA1P5': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.19145728643216084,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.19325153374233126,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.19166666666666676,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.20942408376963348,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.21457696228338433},
 'DNAJA2': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.22261306532663308,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2627811860940696,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.1677083333333333,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.20418848167539266,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.17380224260958205},
 'DNAJA3': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.18040201005025125,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.13087934560327202,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.13749999999999996,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.14136125654450266,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.16666666666666663},
 'DNAJA4': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.45477386934673364,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.23721881390593053,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2833333333333333,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.15811518324607335,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2706422018348623},
 'DNAJB1': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.5793969849246231,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.3548057259713702,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.40520833333333334,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.3036649214659685,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.41743119266055034},
 'DNAJB11': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.31005025125628144,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2678936605316973,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2166666666666666,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.2073298429319371,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.23802242609582047},
 'DNAJB12': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.08492462311557787,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.09713701431492845,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.12604166666666666,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.14764397905759163,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.10448521916411818},
 'DNAJB13': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.04773869346733674,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.07668711656441718,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.04687500000000002,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.0890052356020942,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.06472986748216113},
 'DNAJB14': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.27487437185929653,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.3374233128834357,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.29374999999999996,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.2701570680628273,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.27268093781855235},
 'DNAJB2': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.18643216080402006,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.1462167689161554,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.15937499999999993,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.14554973821989534,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.15239551478083588},
 'DNAJB3': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.09396984924623121,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.10940695296523521,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.07395833333333333,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.10261780104712036,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.09531090723751279},
 'DNAJB4': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.26381909547738686,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.12269938650306751,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.049999999999999954,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.036649214659685826,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.02599388379204892},
 'DNAJB5': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.12311557788944721,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.07157464212678939,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.1291666666666666,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.13717277486910998,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.12181447502548413},
 'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.31909547738693467,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2556237218813906,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.21041666666666672,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.3047120418848168,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.20948012232415897},
 'DNAJB7': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.13015075376884422,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.13905930470347652,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.1729166666666667,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.1445026178010471,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.14424057084607542},
 'DNAJB8': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.042713567839195964,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.03885480572597136,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.04583333333333338,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.03246073298429315,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.063710499490316},
 'DNAJB9': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.17135678391959802,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.09100204498977503,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.05937499999999994,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.05235602094240837,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.07186544342507646},
 'DNAJC1': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.23567839195979898,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.3200408997955011,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.246875,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.21989528795811522,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.24006116207951073},
 'DNAJC10': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.28190954773869353,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.31288343558282217,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.221875,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.20628272251308896,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.27166156982670736},
 'DNAJC11': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.14221105527638192,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.09611451942740282,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.13854166666666667,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.06492146596858639,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.1564729867482161},
 'DNAJC12': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.11507537688442217,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.10838445807770967,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.12291666666666673,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.1298429319371727,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.13812436289500513},
 'DNAJC13': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.35829145728643225,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.43558282208588955,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.41562499999999997,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.4649214659685864,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.35524974515800195},
 'DNAJC14': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.23768844221105523,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.26175869120654405,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2416666666666666,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.22303664921465965,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2543323139653414},
 'DNAJC15': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2597989949748744,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.29652351738241317,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.23124999999999998,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.15602094240837697,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2635066258919469},
 'DNAJC16': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.25778894472361813,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2791411042944786,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2927083333333333,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.27225130890052357,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2737003058103976},
 'DNAJC17': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.08793969849246232,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.114519427402863,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.10520833333333332,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.07748691099476442,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.0922528032619775},
 'DNAJC18': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.0809045226130653,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.07566462167689164,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.06458333333333335,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.02827225130890057,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.09836901121304789},
 'DNAJC19': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.028643216080402028,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.008179959100204507,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.05729166666666674,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.10052356020942407,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.05861365953109074},
 'DNAJC2': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.1522613065326633,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.15848670756646216,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.09166666666666666,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.06073298429319372,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.14424057084607542},
 'DNAJC21': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.20954773869346735,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2106339468302659,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.15208333333333335,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.10471204188481674,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.19520897043832813},
 'DNAJC22': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.05879396984924623,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.1063394683026585,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.11041666666666672,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.07434554973821988,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.0922528032619776},
 'DNAJC24': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.028643216080402028,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.01124744376278122,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.030208333333333337,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.049214659685863846,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.027013251783894042},
 'DNAJC25 /// DNAJC25-GNG10 /// GNG10': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.19145728643216084,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.20040899795501013,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.1947916666666667,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.19685863874345547,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.17787971457696228},
 'DNAJC27': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.04974874371859298,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.07668711656441718,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.04479166666666664,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.05340314136125661,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.08307849133537201},
 'DNAJC28': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.06482412060301512,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.04805725971370141,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.1,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.14764397905759152,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.09021406727828753},
 'DNAJC3': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2648241206030152,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.3006134969325153,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.22916666666666669,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.3329842931937173,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.19317023445463807},
 'DNAJC30': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.12713567839195977,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.114519427402863,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.13541666666666666,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.13821989528795814,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.13608562691131498},
 'DNAJC4 /// NUDT22': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.21959798994974872,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2893660531697342,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2583333333333333,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.33089005235602104,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2359836901121304},
 'DNAJC5': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.242713567839196,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.30470347648261764,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.26145833333333324,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.34136125654450267,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.25535168195718644},
 'DNAJC5B': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.1482412060301508,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.09815950920245399,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.14062500000000006,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.16963350785340314,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.15545361875637106},
 'DNAJC5G': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.09095477386934676,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.07975460122699389,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.09583333333333333,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': -0.11623036649214653,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': -0.11671763506625896},
 'DNAJC6': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.03165829145728639,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.04396728016359915,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.04687499999999993,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.027225130890052424,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.008664627930682973},
 'DNAJC7': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2175879396984925,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.229038854805726,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.16979166666666667,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.18952879581151835,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.1819571865443425},
 'DNAJC8': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.14623115577889448,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.23210633946830264,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.0364583333333333,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.11518324607329848,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.11875637104994903},
 'DNAJC9': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.15527638190954773,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.11758691206543971,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.05937499999999994,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.13403141361256546,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.11162079510703361},
 'LOC646358': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.21959798994974872,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.31186094069529663,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.18854166666666664,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.19685863874345547,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.21865443425076447},
 'ST13': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.45577889447236175,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.3640081799591003,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.39062499999999994,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.31518324607329845,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.4001019367991844},
 'ST13P4': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2507537688442211,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.17995910020449896,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.21875000000000006,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.14345549738219895,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.21457696228338433},
 'ST13P5': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.28190954773869353,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.21370143149284254,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.22604166666666659,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.18010471204188486,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2420998980632008},
 'VEGFA': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2668341708542714,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.24948875255623718,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2708333333333334,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.16439790575916233,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.2319062181447503},
 'VEGFB': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.19547738693467331,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.10838445807770958,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.18854166666666664,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.14345549738219895,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.19011213047910297},
 'VEGFC': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.028643216080402028,
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.005112474437627794,
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.03854166666666668,
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 0.013612565445026165,
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 0.015800203873598304},
 'patient': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 'P1',
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 'P1',
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 'P1',
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': 'P1',
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': 'P1'},
 'time': {'0h_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': '0h',
  '12h_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': '12h',
  '24h_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': '24h',
  '48h_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': '48h',
  '4h_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': '4h'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the x-axis ticks and keep the title of the axis, you can do so by setting the x-axis ticks and leaving the tick string empty.

```
fig.update_layout(title=gene,
                  xaxis_tickvals=obs["patient"],
                  xaxis_ticktext=[''],
                  xaxis_title="Patient",
                  yaxis_title="Gene expression")
```

[image]